# Detectar com javascript toques

Tags: touch

Detectar Varios toques em java escript

Comment: da uma olhada [nesse link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events), ele pode te ajudar

Comment: E [nesse link](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/detecting_touch_swipe_gestures.htm) tbm, para ajudar quem for responder

Comment: Não consegui entender muito bem. Se alguém puder mostrar como seria na prática com um exemplo simplificado, pois estou aprendendo ainda.